# Flutter: Not login Agora RTM

Tags: flutter, rtm

I have a problem when trying to log in with Agora RTM, if the name of the channel and the user is the same it allows me to log in but if the name of the channel is different from the username, it does not allow me to log in, some idea?

Answer (score 0):

Could you give an example of the method calls you're using?
Specifically the login + join channel methods.

You may already be doing this, but you'll need to wait for the login callback before joining a channel.

[Agora Flutter-UIKit](https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Flutter-UIKit) package uses RTM without needing the username + channel to match up.